# Electron multi window in typescript

Tags: javascript, electron

I am using react + typescript + electron. I want to display an HTML element to the new electron window.

Electron only can open a new window by URL. So I found a solution at [here](https://medium.com/@ZoeDreams/multiple-electron-windows-using-a-view-manager-and-react-js-6d8b1e209faf)

This code is written by javascript, and I am a beginner of javascript and typescript.

Error is occurred at

```
let view = ViewManager.Views()[name];
```

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because the expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'Element'.

Also, I cannot understand this code. Could you explain to me this code or change this js code to typescript?

Comment: It depends on what you try to achieve. Do you want to create a modal with your HTML or do you want to create a new window with dynamic content?

Comment: I wanna create new window.

Comment: Please mark correct answers as correct (if they are) using a checkmark. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create new window you should use `BrowserWindow` class. Rendering custom HTML is non-trivial task. You have several options:

1. Pass HTML into new window with URL params like: `file:///your-app-path/view.html?html=<h1>Custom HTML</h1>`. And realize you logic of HTML rendering on your own in `/your-app-path/view.html`.
2. Deliver HTML with inter process communication (IPC) between the main process and the window using [WebContents](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentssendchannel-args) and [ipcRenderer](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer).
3. Use custom protocol to deliver HTML to the window using dynamic page creation. This feature is called "protocol handling". This is a description of [`protocol.registerBufferProtocol()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/protocol#protocolregisterbufferprotocolscheme-handler-completion).

   Here is a working example:

   ```js
    const {app, BrowserWindow, protocol} = require('electron')

    app.whenReady()
    .then(() => {
      let id = 0
      const pages = new Map()

      function openNewWindow(html) {
        const winId = ++id // create new window id
        const hostname = `x${winId}` // create correct hostname

        pages.set(hostname, html)

        const win = new BrowserWindow()
        win.loadURL(`my-protocol://${hostname}`)
        win.on('closed', () => {
          pages.delete(hostname)
        })
      }

      protocol.registerBufferProtocol('my-protocol', (request, callback) => {
        const {hostname} = new URL(request.url)
        const body = pages.get(hostname) || '<html><body><h1>Nothing found</h1></body></html>'
        callback({
          mimeType: 'text/html',
          data: Buffer.from(body),
        })
      }, (error) => {
        if (error) {
          console.error('Failed to register protocol')
        }
      })

      openNewWindow(`
        <html>
          <head><title>Test</title></head>
          <body>
            <h1>It works</h1>
          </body>
        </html>
      `)
    })
   ```

Comment: I solved my problem in other way, but your answer is useful. Thank you